# Exposing all the globals in FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

```
<#list .globals?keys as vals>
${vals}
</#list>


FreeMarker template error: For "?keys" left-hand operand: Expected an extended
hash, but this has evaluated to a hash (wrapper: f.c.Environment$4):
==> .globals  [in template "contents/globals.ftl" at line 9, column 8]
```

In other words, how to render the keys of a hash which is not extended in FreeMarker? (I'm using node.js with fmpp, rather than developing in Java)

Comment: Globals are unlistable, but do you indeed want the globals, or rather the `.data_model` variables? (Which I can't remember if is listable in the case of FMPP...)

Comment: The globals, yes. Thanks. Was hoping to view them all this way, rather than searching through files.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, the keys of `globals` are not accessible. `globals` are a hash and no extended hash. This means, you can not access their keys and values using the [built-ins for hashes](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html).

You can tell if a hash is extended (and thus supports those built-ins) by using [is_hash_ext](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html).